# Remove duplicate record from table

Tags: mysql

I have a table in MySQL named ZipCode and its fields are: id, zipcode, city, state.   It has some duplicate records; some zipcode are showing two times 
I want to remove all that zipcodes that are coming twice; each zipcode must be stored just once.
How can I make it correct?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Delete Duplicate SQL Records](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/841447/delete-duplicate-sql-records)

Answer (score 7):

```
-- remove duplicates

DELETE z1
FROM ZipCode z1, ZipCode z2
WHERE z1.zipcode = z2.zipcode AND z2.id < z1.id;

-- add a primary key

ALTER TABLE ZipCode ADD PRIMARY KEY (zipcode);

-- or a unique key

ALTER TABLE ZipCode ADD UNIQUE INDEX zipcode_unique (zipcode);
```

Answer (score 4):

This set of three queries will remove all duplicates:

```
CREATE TABLE new_table AS SELECT * FROM old_table WHERE 1 GROUP BY zip;
DROP TABLE old_table;
RENAME TABLE new_table TO old_table;
```

Comment: and don't forget to re-create indexes and constraints after that :)

Comment: ... _and_ introduce a primary-key constraint on the new table to prevent recurrence,

Comment: Yup, true. And also, fix the code that was inserting duplicates to have it check that the row it is inserting is unique.

Comment: You could change this to `CREATE TABLE new_table LIKE old_table; INSERT INTO new_table SELECT * FROM old_table WHERE 1 GROUP BY zip;` to avoid having to recreate indices and such.

Answer (score 0):

Try this its working fine

```
DELETE
FROM
insurance_policy_customers ipc
WHERE
ipc.id NOT IN (SELECT
min(ipc.id)
FROM
insurance_policy_customers ipc
GROUP BY
ipc.resident_insurance_policy_id )
```