# How to delete duplicates on a MySQL table by date and id?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with results that come from an app.
Some of the results are duplicate and I can see which "`survey_question_id`" has duplicate answers.

With this query I can see how many duplicates I have for each "`survey_question_id`":

```
    SELECT `id`,`survey_question_id`,
   `question`,`date`, COUNT(*) 
   FROM answers 
   GROUP BY `survey_question_id`, `date` 
   HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 and `date` > '2015-10-15'
```

**Table Results:**

[image]

How can I delete duplicates?

Comment: You want to delete all of those answers or want to keep only one of duplicate answers for each question?

Comment: @TareqMahmood I want to keep only one of duplicate answers for each question.

Comment: @JayBlanchard it's not the same because to be duplicate it must have the same survey_question_id, question and date.

Comment: No, not true. Deleting duplicates from MySQL is a general concept and typically not specifically related to column names and / or data.

Comment: Possibly you could use that solution if you have a field with only date ( not included time)

Comment: @JayBlanchard always learning. Thanks

Comment: @TareqMahmood date and time are on the same field. Maybe in the future we will separate them into different fields.

Comment: There was an answer that solved my problem but it was deleted. The user was PhizerFernandes. Is it possible to recover it?

Comment: @pmcmf I suggest to create a unique index for resolving this issue

Answer (score 2):

You can

1. **create table your_table2 as select distinct * from original_table** and then just
2. drop original_table with some cascade constraints and
3. alter your_table2, rename it and add back all constraints 
   **or** just delete all data from original_table and do just insert into original_table select * from your_table2

I think that [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5363365/removing-duplicate-rows-from-a-mysql-table) is similar to your problem.

Comment: Nice approach to save data in tmp table ist

Answer (score 1):

For Duplicate records deletion, you can use this:

**IF you want to keep LOWEST id than you can use this:**

```
DELETE n1 FROM answers n1, answers n2 WHERE n1.id > n2.id 
AND n1.id <> n2.id
AND n1.survey_question_id = n2.survey_question_id 
AND n1.question = n2.question 
AND n1.date = n2.date
```

**IF you want to keep HIGEST id than you can use this:**

```
DELETE n1 FROM answers n1, answers n2 WHERE n1.id < n2.id 
AND n1.id <> n2.id
AND n1.survey_question_id = n2.survey_question_id 
AND n1.question = n2.question 
AND n1.date = n2.date
```

Add **UNIQUE INDEX** if you think this can be happened again in future.

```
ALTER IGNORE TABLE answers   
ADD UNIQUE INDEX (id,survey_question_id,
   question,date);
```

**Side Note:** please make sure you have a **copy** of this table before executing any kind of **bulk Deletion**.

Comment: I tried this but gives the result: MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows).

Comment: @pmcmf how many column do u have in this table 4?

Comment: @pmcmf: i have updated my answer

Comment: yours is similar to this one:
DELETE a1 FROM answers a1, answers a2
WHERE a1.id> a2.id
AND a1.survey_question_id = a2.survey_question_id
AND a1.question = a2.question
AND a1.date = a2.date
AND a1.date > '2015-10-15'

Comment: No @pmcmf > < diff only

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DELETE FROM answers
WHERE date > '2015-10-15'
AND id NOT IN 
  (SELECT id
      FROM (SELECT MIN(id) AS id  FROM answers
            WHERE date > '2015-10-15'
            GROUP BY survey_question_id) x
  )
```

Comment: Its very risky query

Comment: This would delete a bunch of good data while leaving duplicates in the system.  Based on the data in the screenshot, the 2 duplicates of ID 141450 would be left intact, and all other data (in the screenshot) would be destroyed.

Comment: Sorry but this one does not work. Thanks anyway