# Remove duplicate rows based on a value in a field

Tags: mysql, duplicates, min

I have a very large table (several million records). SOME records have duplicates (based on FieldA) where the only difference is a value in FiedldB. I'd like to create a query that will remove all duplicate records based on FieldA, keeping the one with the lowest value in FieldB. Is this possible?

Comment: Yes, this is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems pretty straightforward to extract these values:

```
select distinct a, 
       min(b)   b 
from t
group by a;
```

Fiddle for example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bc4c9/3

You should be able to adapt a removal method from this.

Comment: I ran this using limit 100 and it ran fine. When I ran w/o it maxes out tmp file very quickly. Is there a way to run a query like this where it flushes tmp or am I going to manually run in batches e.g Where ID>0 and ID <100? That will sort of suck as there are 1/2 million records or so.

Comment: Why are you writing to a temp file? I thought you wanted to delete records.

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TABLE TABLE1
  (
    FieldA VARCHAR2(30),
    FieldB VARCHAR2(30),
    FieldC VARCHAR2(30)
  );

INSERT INTO TABLE1 VALUES
  ('DUMMYDATA-A1','DUMMYDATA-B1','DUMMYDATA-C1'
  );
INSERT INTO TABLE1 VALUES
  ('DUMMYDATA-A1','DUMMYDATA-B4','DUMMYDATA-C1'
  );
INSERT INTO TABLE1 VALUES
  ('DUMMYDATA-A1','DUMMYDATA-B3','DUMMYDATA-C1'
  );
INSERT INTO TABLE1 VALUES
  ('DUMMYDATA-A1','DUMMYDATA-B2','DUMMYDATA-C1'
  );
COMMIT;

SELECT FieldA,
  FieldB,
  FieldC,
  RANK() OVER( PARTITION BY FieldA ORDER BY FieldB ASC) AS COLUMN_ALIAS
FROM TABLE1; --IDENTIFIES DUPLICATES BASED ON RANK VALUE

---PERFORM DELETE
DELETE
FROM TABLE1
WHERE ROWID IN
  (SELECT ROWID
  FROM
    (SELECT ROWID,
      RANK() OVER( PARTITION BY FieldA ORDER BY FieldB ASC) AS COLUMN_ALIAS
    FROM TABLE1
    )
  WHERE COLUMN_ALIAS>1
  );

COMMIT;

SELECT * FROM TABLE1; -- CONTAINS A SINGLE RECORD
```

RANK function can identify the duplicate records and facilitate deleting only the duplicated record , retaining the original row. This has been already discussed here : [Deleting duplicates rows from oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9544605/deleting-duplicates-rows-from-oracle) . Hope this helps

However as DELETE itself is slower, proper constraints can be implemented in this scenario (contains millions of records) at the INSERT to avoid duplicate entry.