# Deleting duplicate rows in oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

Shouldn't the following query work fine for deleting duplicate rows in oracle

```
SQL> delete from sessions o 
      where 1<=(select count(*) 
                  from sessions i 
                 where i.id!=o.id 
                   and o.data=i.data);
```

It seems to delete all the duplication rows!! (I wish to keep 1 tough)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Removing duplicate rows from table in Oracle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/529098/removing-duplicate-rows-from-table-in-oracle)

Comment: thanks for the solution, but why this dosent seem to work fine?

Answer (score 2):

Your statement doesn't work because your table has at least one row where two different `ID`'s share the same values for `DATA`.

Although your *intent* may be to look for differing values of `DATA` `ID` by `ID`, what your SQL is *saying* is in fact set-based:  "Look at my table as a whole.  If there are any rows in the table such that the `DATA` is the same but the `ID`'s are different (i.e., that inner `COUNT(*)` is anything greater than 0), then `DELETE` every row in the table."

You may be attempting specific, row-based logic, but your statement is big-picture (set-based).  There's nothing in it to single out duplicate rows, as there is in the solution Ollie has linked to, for example.