# Delete rows where certain value occurs more than once SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Removing duplicate rows from table in Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/529098/removing-duplicate-rows-from-table-in-oracle)

Here's an example of what I currently have:

```
ID        Name1    Name2
ABC123    Bob      Jones
ABC123    Bob      Smith
ABC123    Bob      Hammond
DEF234    Tim      Whatever
```

I'd like the table above to look like this:

```
ID        Name1    Name2
ABC123    Bob      Jones
DEF234    Tim      Whatever
```

I'd like to delete all rows where the ID field is shared, I don't care which ones are kept or deleted, just that the number of total rows is equal to the number of unique IDs.

Comment: Are you allowed to use pl/sql?

Comment: @Reimius, yes PL/SQL is an option.

Answer (score 3):

```
DELETE FROM YOURTABLE Y WHERE ROWID > (SELECT min(rowid) FROM YOURTABLE X
WHERE X.ID = Y.ID)
```

Comment: What exactly do the X and Y represent?

Comment: They are table aliases. For example once you write YOUTABLE X, you can use X instead of YOURTABLE in that query. So, they represent YOURTABLE, or whatever the name of your table.You dont have to use X or Y, you can use any characters or words (except reserved words in Oracle).

Comment: I see now, that did the trick. Thanks bonsvr!

Comment: Can you mark this as correct solr?  I almost just tried answering this myself.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have global unique ID for whatever reason, then something like this should work:

```
DELETE FROM Table WHERE CONCAT(ID,Name1,Name2) NOT IN ( 
       SELECT MIN(CONCAT(ID,Name1,Name2)) FROM Table GROUP BY ID)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 DELETE FROM your_table
      WHERE ROWID IN (
               SELECT rid
                  FROM (SELECT ROWID rid,
                           ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY ROWID) rn
                         FROM your_table)
                WHERE rn <> 1);
```

Comment: @J.Chomel I don't understand the suggestion you made ?I just grouped by based on the ID column in my example

Comment: sorry, posted on wrong page.