# How to find duplicate names in a table

Tags: sql, string, duplicates, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a table having person names address and job title.
the names are repeating sometimes. I have to compare if two people have the same name and same address than i have to keep only 1 record of them.

```
Table: Data_Excel
Name: P_Name
Address: P_Address
City:  P_city
```

Comment: See this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/529098/removing-duplicate-rows-from-table-in-oracle

Comment: Er, what about the possibility of two _different_ people with the same name and address?  Like two John Smiths in a fraternity?  Or a married couple with unisex names?  Is that something you need to worry about?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

To find the duplicates you can do:

```
SELECT P_name,
  P_Address,
  P_city
FROM Data_Excel
GROUP BY P_Name,
  P_Address,
  P_city
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

To remove duplicates you could do:

```
DELETE
FROM Data_Excel
WHERE rowid NOT IN (
    SELECT MIN(rowid)
    FROM Data_Excel
    GROUP BY P_Name,
      P_Address,
      P_city
    );
```

To Insert in Person table you would do:

```
INSERT INTO Person(id,name)
SELECT (SELECT MAX(id)+1 FROM Person),P_Name 
FROM Data_Excel WHERE P_Name NOT IN (SELECT name FROM Person)
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response, now if i have to insert the names in Person table with ID and Name from Data_excel table with checking: Name should be added once Name should not exist in person table already

Comment: @user408437. I added a simplistic way of doing that.

Comment: If i dont delete the duplicate values FROM Data_Excel and than do the insert? and the ID in persons table is not auto incrementing by itself in that case how can i take the last id and increment the values of ID for each insert?

Comment: I edited my answer. Any reason not to do the auto_incremented id?

Comment: Thanks, Just to be sure this query will insert names from Data_excel to Person table and if a name already exists than "WHERE P_Name NOT IN (SELECT name FROM Person)" will make sure its not already inserted?

Comment: Itried the query and got the following error:

*Cause:    An UPDATE or INSERT statement attempted to insert a duplicate key.
           For Trusted Oracle configured in DBMS MAC mode, you may see
           this message if a duplicate entry exists at a different level.
*Action:   Either remove the unique restriction or do not insert the key.

Comment: Can you put both table structures exactly like you have them in [sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlifddle.com) and share the link?

Comment: Pleqse find the table structues qs follows:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/bz3bu89ehjpom93/Data_excel.png

Comment: Copy that to sqlfiddle. It makes it easier to test the queries

Comment: The error is because if i insert more than 1 row, (SELECT MAX(id)+1 FROM Person) always gives the same value can i use sequence to do it?

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT P_Name,P_Address,count(*)
FROM Data_Excel
GROUP BY P_Name,P_Address
HAVING count(*) > 1;
```

This will give you the records with same `P_Name` & `P_Address`.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response, now if i have to insert the names in Person table with ID and Name from Data_excel table with checking:

Name should be added once

Name should not exist in person table already

Comment: you want to first check that names exist in the `person` table? if not than insert them and if yes than do nothing? Is that what you want?

Comment: Yes indeed and in case i have multiple entries in Data_excel i only enter the name once.