# Transactional level for subqueries

Tags: oracle, subquery

I want to remove duplicate rows from the table and found this solution at SO ([Removing duplicate rows from table in Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/529098/removing-duplicate-rows-from-table-in-oracle))

```
DELETE FROM your_table -- step 2
WHERE rowid not in
(SELECT MIN(rowid) -- step 1
FROM your_table
GROUP BY column1, column2, column3);
```

What will happen if there are rows inserted after Step 1 but before Step 2, will they be deleted as well? If yes, what transactional level should I use to avoid it?

Answer (score 1):

From [the concepts guide](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e40540/consist.htm#BABEIHGJ):

> In the read committed isolation level, which is the default, every
>   query executed by a transaction sees only data committed before the
>   query—not the transaction—began.
>
> ...
>
> A query in a read committed transaction avoids reading data that
>   commits while the query is in progress.
>
> ...
>
> A consistent result set is provided for every query, guaranteeing data
>   consistency, with no action by the user. An implicit query, such as a
>   query implied by a `WHERE` clause in an `UPDATE` statement, is
>   guaranteed a consistent set of results. However, each statement in an
>   implicit query does not see the changes made by the DML statement
>   itself, but sees the data as it existed before changes were made.

The last paragraph applies to your case as well, just for `DELETE` rather than `UPDATE`. Your statement - the delete itself and the subquery are a single statement - is isolated so it won't be affected by any changes made in any other sessions or transactions. You won't 'see' any rows inserted elsewhere while your statement is executed, whether they are commited or not.

So you don't need to change from the default isolation level.