# Remove duplicates from mysql with no primary key

Tags: mysql

```
   select count(distinct (mobile)) from number_data where value = 'A_HNI';

   count(distinct (mobile)) = 5046082 



  select count(mobile) from number_data where value = 'A_HNI';

  count(mobile) = 9658150
```

There are 4612068 duplicates of mobile numbers in value = 'A_HNI'. I want to delete the  duplicates and keep the original . The table has no primary key nor indexing .                                                                                                               I can't assign a primary key but indexing is possible .                                   The table is as follows :

Field     Type          Null  Key  Default  Extra

title    | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |

name     | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |

age      | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |

pincode  | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |

city     | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |

state    | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |

mobile   | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |

source   | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |

value    | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |

dnd      | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |

msc      | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |

operator | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |

Comment: Which of the duplicates do you want to keep?

Answer (score 1):

Get the `Distinct` value from your table ,create a new table with it then `delete` the old table 
For reference you can check this page
[Remove Duplicate Value](http://www.orafaq.com/faq/how_does_one_eliminate_duplicates_rows_from_a_table)

You can also refer this stack answer[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/529098/removing-duplicate-rows-from-table-in-oracle)

Comment: I have multiple clauses example where value = 'A_HNI' , where value = 'a' , where value = 'b'. so i have to create separate table for each and then combine them ??