# How to delete Duplicate Data in sql oracle using index?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have duplicate data in my table. Give the easiest code to delete the Duplicate data using index.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Removing duplicate rows from table in Oracle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/529098/removing-duplicate-rows-from-table-in-oracle)

Comment: Just use DISTINCT or GROUP BY, the usage of index depends on predicates in your WHERE clause.

Comment: SO is not a coding service; if you have a problem, do some search, try something and then, if you have a specific question on your code, post it here.

Comment: Explain why you state "using index". Are you having some problem with index not used?

Comment: Add some sample table data, both before and after the delete. And show us your current query attempt!

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE FROM dublicate_table
WHERE row_id not in
(SELECT MIN(row_id)
FROM dublicate_table
GROUP BY column1, column2, column3);
```

Column1, column2, and column3 make up the identifying key for each record. You might list all your columns.