# Remove Duplicate ids from select query

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

I have the following table

```
ID     NAME    POINT
100    AAA     100
100    AAA     150
100    AAA     70
200    DDD     100
200    DDD     65
300    FFF     50
```

I would like to delete duplicate id from this table. I would like to get below

```
ID     NAME    POINT
100    AAA     100
200    DDD     100
300    FFF     50
```

I already used `DISTINCT` keyword in my select query likes this

```
SELECT DISTINCT ID,NAME,POINT FROM Tab ORDER BY ID;
```

It is not ok. I just need one unique id per record.So How to remove duplicate ids from select query? My condition is If all records are the same then take the first record.

Comment: Based on what condition?

Comment: For each ID, how to chose which row to return?

Comment: you want to delete record from existing table or select unique records?

Comment: You could do something like SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM Tab; to get only the distinct ids, but with different values in POINT the keyword DISTINCT will always return all rows, as they are different in your current query.

Comment: @SushilMate No I want delete the records from select query. (logical delete)

Comment: But in SQL rows are un-ordered, there is no _first row_, unless you specify how to order the rows.

Comment: @jarlh order by id

Comment: But you want within each ID group...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Removing duplicate rows from table in Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/529098/removing-duplicate-rows-from-table-in-oracle)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE #Table1
    ([ID] int, [NAME] varchar(3), [POINT] int)
;

INSERT INTO #Table1
    ([ID], [NAME], [POINT])
VALUES
    (100, 'AAA', 100),
    (100, 'AAA', 150),
    (100, 'AAA', 70),
    (200, 'DDD', 100),
    (200, 'DDD', 65),
    (300, 'FFF', 50)

SELECT ID,NAME,POINT FROM (SELECT* , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY ID,NAME ) AS RN FROM #TABLE1)A
WHERE RN=1
```

output

```
ID     NAME    POINT
100    AAA     100
200    DDD     100
300    FFF     50
```

Comment: You've been faster than me ;) +1

Comment: Isn't that SQL Server syntax? Will it run on Oracle as well?

Comment: i would add ORDER BY ID; NAME, POINT - as it seems he wants do keep the rows with the maximum Points

Comment: @jarlh, No, Oracle well knows [ROW_NUMBER](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions137.htm) function. Please follow the link.

Answer (score 4):

I think the easiest option is a to `group by` statement. That is:

```
SELECT ID, NAME, POINT GROUP BY ID
```

You might need to add some other logic, deepening on what `POINT` value you want to select (e.g. max, min etc). That is:

```
SELECT ID, NAME, MAX(POINT) GROUP BY ID, NAME
```

Comment: OP defined an issue as: `My condition is If all records are the same then take the **first record**.` So, using Max() does not meet criteria.

Comment: My understanding is that the GROUP BY takes the first row that has a duplicate and discards any rows that match after it in the result set. So the first version (with no aggregat function) should return the first value.

Comment: I would also echo jarlh's comment above -  i.e. SQL rows are un-ordered, there is no 'first' row, unless you specify how to order the rows.

Comment: @djmac Your first statement is not valid. Columns not in the group by must be in an aggregate.

Comment: @MaciejLos In the comments to the question the ops writes that he wants the results "order by id", which pretty much means a random `POINT` within the group. At least using `Max` would give consistent results.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `rowid` pseudocolumn.

```
DELETE FROM your_table
WHERE rowid not in (SELECT MIN(rowid) FROM your_table GROUP BY id, name);
```

If you have more columns in your PK, add them in the `group by` list.