# How to delete the row in table user_role_privs in oracle

Tags: oracle, delete-row

Accidently i have created the 2 rows for each DBA and AQ_ADMINISTRATOR_ROLE in table user_roles_privs, can you let me know how i can delete 1 row of each and also the query to delete.

This is the current state of the table:

[image: database table screenshot]

Thanks
Nilesh

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Removing duplicate rows from table in Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/529098/removing-duplicate-rows-from-table-in-oracle)

Answer (score 2):

You are getting these records as you/someone must have given these roles to your user - `C##234`. You need to revoke the role from your user as follows:

```
REVOKE AQ_ADMINISTRATOR_ROLE FROM C##234; -- You can execute same for DBA
```

Please make sure that you are executing the command from user with DBA rights.

Read more about `REVOKE` from Oracle documentation [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_9020.htm)

Comment: Thanks, it worked but the AQ_ADMINISTRATOR_ROLE with the admin option as yes has been deleted and when i am again running the grant command it is making the new row . Basically i want the Admin option as yes and Common as yes for both DBA and AQ_ADMINISTRATOR_ROLE. Thanks

Comment: If you want admin option as YES then you need to grant the role with admin option.

Comment: yes i have done that but it is creating a new row and not letting me change in the existing row , if the new row will be created than common will become no, but i want both to be yes.

Comment: This is how oracle has implemented its internal code and it is also mentioned in the given oracle document.