# running delete command to remove duplicate in oracle with cte is giving ora-00928 error

Tags: sql, oracle, duplicates, common-table-expression

I am runnig the below query to delete duplicate from my table, but its giving the below error:

```
with cte as (select  name,address,designation, row_number() over(partition by name,address,designation order by name) rn from emp)
delete from cte where rn <>1;
select * from emp;
```

Error: **ORA-00928: missing SELECT keyword**

How to fix this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Removing duplicate rows from table in Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/529098/removing-duplicate-rows-from-table-in-oracle)

Answer (score 2):

You can't delete from a CTE or an inline view.

What I always use:

```
delete emp
where  rowid in
       ( select lag(rowid) over (partition by name,address,designation order by name)
         from   emp );
```

There are a lot of more complicated approaches over on [Removing duplicate rows from table in Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/529098/removing-duplicate-rows-from-table-in-oracle)